# Get mouse button state in OSX

Tags: macos, core-graphics, mouse, quartz-core

Is there any way to query the state of mouse buttons in OSX? In other words, I am looking for a function that returns whether a mouse button is currently being pressed or not. The equivalent under Windows would be `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)`.

This is in the context of a Quartz event if that matters. I found the promising function [CGEventSourceFlagsState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1408792-cgeventsourceflagsstate?language=objc) that, when called with [kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventsourcestateid/kcgeventsourcestatehidsystemstate?language=objc) returns that information for the CONTROL, SHIFT, ALT keys but from what I can see, unfortunately not for mouse buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [CGEventSourceButtonState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1408781-cgeventsourcebuttonstate?language=objc) might just be what I am looking for.